# New Blender Version with the Same Old Startup File

Tags: startup-file

I have put a lot of time to create my own tailored startup file in my Blender 2.91.2. Now I wish to download version 2.93.1. Can you please advise what should I do in order to make sure that my startup file is kept operational with the new downloaded version? Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Open the old blender, and save the file it starts up to in your documents folder.
Install new blender.
Open the save, and save it as your startup file.

Comment: TheLabCat, thanks a lot for your help. Exactly what I needed 